# Any free bitcoind vps?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, hosting

So let's say I'm developing a mining device that has some basic Ethernet or Wifi capabilities, but defiantly cannot run bitcoind. Let's also say that this device is open-source, so I cannot host a server for all of everyone. Is there some server somewhere that is running bitcoind that all of these devices could access (for free) or are there only paid options?

Comment: So you can't host a server for all of everyone, but you expect somebody else to offer that service for free? Seems unrealistic.

Comment: Well I didn't know if there was a good way to, lets say, access the raw info from blockchain.info

Comment: This is effectively what a mining pool does, right?  The pool operator runs bitcoind and serves the miners just the data that they need.  It's not exactly free, since the pool operator will take a cut of the mining revenue, but it is probably more like what you want.  Having direct access to a bitcoind is only useful if you want to solo mine, which is likely not what your customers want unless your device is remarkably powerful.

Comment: Thats true, ill probably find a pool